# What type of mushroom/fungus is this?

Tags: species-identification, mycology

I had someone gift me some old firewood along with some other wood I had purchased from them.  I was told the wood in question is [popple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Populus_tremuloides).  However, it was in pretty bad shape and much of it had a mushroom/fungus growing on it.

Does anyone recognize this fungi?  The trees lived in central Minnesota, and sat close to a lake for a year or so.

[image: mystery mushroom]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are shelf (or [bracket) fungi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket_fungus). They love dead or diseased wood, and are as common in woods as dirt.

Yours are kind of in rough shape (it looks like they're experiencing some problems of their own.) It's hard without examining a specimen to determine exactly which it is.

[image]

Some are edible, some are beautifully colored, some are hard, some soft, some plump, etc. But they are all shelf fungi.